How to safe the best mask result while using SAM (Segment Anything Model) with multimask_output=False?
I want to safe the best mask result from the SamPredictor while having multimask_output=False.
I came across this example:
# Initialize SAM
sam_checkpoint = "sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth"
model_type = "vit_h"
device = "cuda"
sam = sam_model_registry[model_type](checkpoint=sam_checkpoint)
sam.to(device=device)
predictor = SamPredictor(sam)
image = cv2.imread('images/truck.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
predictor.set_image(image)


input_point = np.array([[500, 375], [1125, 625]])
input_label = np.array([1, 0])

mask_input = logits[np.argmax(scores), :, :]  # Choose the model's best mask

masks, _, _ = predictor.predict(
    point_coords=input_point,
    point_labels=input_label,
    mask_input=mask_input[None, :, :],
    multimask_output=False,
)

Result
I tried this code but it's not working because logits and scores are used before they are defined. How do I save the best mask?
